# jQuery findIndex() not working in IE, but works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have this line of code:

```
var index = $scope.dateTimeSlots.findIndex(x => x.id == selectedItem);
```

But it keeps giving me a syntax error in IE 11....This works in Chrome perfectly but not in IE 11...why? and how do I fix it?

Comment: IE doesn't support `findIndex()` (or arrow functions) .. you need to use a polyfill for it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dateTimeSlots.length; i++) {

                if ($scope.dateTimeSlots[i].id == selectedItem) {
                    index = i
                }

            }
```

I hate Internet Explorer

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.